# SQL Server service dependency not working

Tags: windows-services, dependencies, ms-sql

I have an service that tries to connect to a MSSQL DB on startup, but when I start the computer it throws an error becouse it's not able to connect to the DB. This happens becouse the specific DB was not started by the MSSQL Service yet, even though my service has a dependecy set for the MSSQL Service.

What can I do? Any solutions?

I could add a delay to my service of let's say 5 minutes, but that would be the last solution I would use as it's not a proper one from my point of view. [image]

LE : Forgot to say, it must work on windows XP SP3, I've tried with auto-delay but it won't work.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9687871/database-clients-how-to-wait-for-database-activation-after-sql-server-restart

Comment: For XP, see the [DependOnService](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc963243.aspx) registry entry, whose use is explained in the article [Delayed Start for Windows XP](http://vibrations.csscorp.com/vibrations/sep_2011/windows_xp.html).

Comment: It's there it's set as it should be, it still doesn't work!

Comment: Can you mark something as solution, ir even post your own solution?

Comment: @davidbaumann done, i've installed Windows 7. Used the Delayed Start option.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Set your service to Automatic (Delayed Start)? This will delay it by 2 minutes until after the last automatic service has started.

Comment: As you may have not read my last line, it must work on Win XP which does not have an Delayed Start option.

Answer (score 0):

Set the service you want to delay to manual.

Now go to your SQL Server console and follow this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/287060/scheduled-run-of-stored-procedure-on-sql-server

Create a command like this:

```
xp_cmdshell 'net start yourservice'
```

I hope this helps, cannot test here. I guess it needs the sql server agent for this.

Comment: I can't use SQL Agent but thank you for trying.

Answer (score 0):

One can [Schedule a Task in Windows XP](https://support.microsoft.com/kb/308569?wa=wsignin1.0) that will launch a batch file that will start
the service whenever you want, relative to a triggering event.

The triggering event can be simple, such as `At Logon`, which will certainly only happen after
a certain delay.

For more control, when creating the task
click Open in the Advanced properties for the task before clicking Finish.
In the Properties dialog box for the task one can specify more conditions :

[image]